# How can i play DRM protected video in electron js desktop app

Tags: electron, drm, brightcove

I have embedded Iframe with source containing video url.
BUt
I am getting error :

ERROR: (CODE:5 MEDIA_ERR_ENCRYPTED) requestMediaKeySystemAccess is disabled by feature policy.

and sometime i get

code: 6001, type: "REQUESTED_KEY_SYSTEM_CONFIG_UNAVAILABLE", headline: "DRM: REQUESTED_KEY_SYSTEM_CONFIG_UNAVAILABLE", message: ""}